# Could you explain what did I do wrong?

Tags: graphics

I don't understand why I still got error message.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\title{Quantum Mechanics Homework 3 \& 4}
\author{Seng Sopheak}
\date{2014}
\maketitle
[...]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{QM HM 3_2.jpg}
\end{figure}
[...]
\end{document}
```

This is the error message I always got:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.346 \includegraphics{QM HM 3_2.jpg}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: It is the underscore in the file name. Try using `\includegraphics{"QM HM 3_2"}`. I'd recommend not using spaces and special LaTeX characters in file names.